# What are the hand signs that Naruto does for Multi Shadow Clone Jutsu?

Tags: naruto

What are the hand signs that Naruto does for Multi Shadow Clone Jutsu?

Answer (score 2):

The hand signs used to evoke the Multi-Shadow Clone Jutsu aren't different than the standard Shadow Clone Jutsu. The *only* difference is the amount of chakra consumed during the execution of the jutsu.

Answer (score -3):

The hand signs are given below:

[image: two muppets]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: These aren't the signs for Shadow Clone or Multi-Shadow Close Justu. This is just a screenshot of all the hand signs

Comment: Wait, thats what he asked for right?

Comment: The question is is referring only to the hand signs used for the specified jutsu.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be downvoted, all it really needs is a line or two specifying the specific signals and the order they appear in to fully answer the question. Additional information isn't a bad thing per se.

Comment: @Matt i would argue that it should be downvoted as on the surface it isn't clear if these hard signs are for the Multi Shadow Clone Jutsu or if as Wondercricket said, these are just a bunch of hand signs